# github action that I can't run

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I'm relatively new to Git Hub, and the problem is I have created 2 branches main, dev.
dev is not protected anyone can push on it and main is push-protected only upon PRs.
I want to create a GitHub workflow as follows

```
name: Code coverage & flake8

on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Set up Python 3.8
          uses: actions/setup-python@v2
          with:
            python-version: 3.8
        - name: Install dependencies
          run: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install -r requirements.txt
        - name: Lint with flake8
          run: |
           pip install flake8
              flake8
        - name: Coverage report
          run: |
            pip install coverage
            coverage run manage.py test
            coverage report
            coverage HTML`
```

however, this workflow doesn't appear on the GitHub actions tab.
I have tried to push it into main to test it and it starts to appear but I can't run it manually also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to merge your workflow file to the default branch, before it shall appear in the Actions tab of your repo.

Second, you had set it to trigger on `push`.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
    workflow_dispatch:
```

You need to update it to:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
  workflow_dispatch:
```

So that you can manually trigger the workflow as well (once the above code is merged).